# Navigate to report server from asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

what i did till now is deployed SSRS reports i.e rdl files on report server. And provided a direct link from my app as anchor tag to visit that report. But now we have a problem that it asks for credentials.

We need to do a behaviour where we should have a web page in our application that will  have some fields and a button. On click of a button, we need to redirect user to report server to show a particular report but user should not be prompted with user name & password i.e it should handle authentication internally.

so, how can i do such type of redirection where we authenticate it internally in asp.net mvc application. Moreover can i also pass search parameters?

Comment: Have you considered embedding the report viewer control in your application, so as to display the report in it rather than redirecting to the report manager portal?

Comment: I am told not to use report viewer. Just to redirect to report server with auto authentication.

Comment: You can pass parameters in the URL but I don't think you'll be able to handle the authentication: by that point it has gone to the report portal.